# (react native) Adding a new key/value in JSON is throwing an error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this JSON object

```
settingsAndImages = "images": null;
```

When I try to add something to it, such as

`settingsAndImages["images"]["key"] = "value"`, I get this error:

```
 TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'settingsAndImages["images"]["key"] = "value"')
```

I think this is weird because I thought you were supposed to be able to add key/value pairs just by doing that?

Comment: The first line of code you posted is invalid syntax, so I'm not even sure how you got to the error you posted. As for that, you cannot add properties to null, and it's not clear what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: it was settingsAndImages["images"] = {"images": null} actually.

Comment: And I'm trying to create an entire new key value pair. I want to change settingsAndImages["images"] to equal {"key": "value"}

Comment: In that case, you are looking for `settingsAndImages["images"] = { ["key"]: null }`. But this is not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can first define the "images" as an object. Then you can add key and value to it.

```
settingsAndImages["images"] = {};
settingsAndImages["images"]["key"] = "value"
```

Comment: I think this would've been my best bet had I not found my other solution. I don't know if it would've worked but I'd like to think it would've.

Answer (score 0):

You can add key/value like this instead:

```
settingsAndImages["images"] = {"key" : "value"};

console.log(settingsAndImages)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers. For some reason, settingsAndImages["images"] was being compiled as read-only, but settingsAndImages["settings"] wasn't, so I just did

```
settingsAndImages["settings"][storeName]["image"] = base64Image
```

If anyone has any theories as to why settingsAndImages["images"] was coming up as read-only, I'd love to hear it! It was very strange having one key in a JSON object be read-only and the other being editable.